# Nest: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open

Tags: angular, nestjs

I'm creating a saml strategy and I created a certs folder with my keys in it. The problem is that when I build the project I get this error:

```
[Nest] 14078   - 04/22/2020, 4:33:34 PM   [ExceptionHandler] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/wilsonsilva/Desktop/EduTec/formations-tool/dist/server-app/src/auth/certs/key.pem' +115ms
```

So when I went to the specified path (dist folder) the folder *certs* folder was indeed missing. Can someone help me find a solution?

I'm using Angular 8 with Ng Universal (NestJS)

Comment: Did you try searching this site for `[angular] ENOENT no such file`? It appears to have several existing questions and answers that might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not expert on SAML. However, usually these kind of problems are solved by

- Having a build step to copy the files to `/dist/` folder after the build.
- Modify your config so that it tries to find a `key.pem` from some absolute path and then you can separately configure this path on your production server
- Just copy-paste `key.pem` inside your TypeScript source as a string and not refer to it as a file

Answer (score 0):

delete the dist folders and then restart your project

Comment: It is not working.